# How do I get value of a column from select operation and use it in another select operation in a stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetLoginInformation
(
    @userid INT OUTPUT,
    @UserName NVARCHAR(50),
    @Password NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT @userid = UserId 
               FROM tblLoginInfo 
               WHERE UserName = @UserName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
                 AND Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
    BEGIN
        SELECT *  
        FROM tblUserInformation 
        WHERE UserId = @userid
    END
END
```

Comment: Formatting is not proper and description of the requirements or issue is not clear

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Decalred a Variable @COL to use it in other Query.

Please check the modified procedure with comments.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetLoginInformation ( @userid int output, @UserName nvarchar(50), @Password nvarchar(50) ) as 
begin 
  ------ VARIABLE TO STORE INFORMATION FROM SELECT STATEMENT
  DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50);
  IF EXISTS (Select @userid=UserId from tblLoginInfo where UserName=@UserName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS and Password=@Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) 
  BEGIN 
  ------ ASSIGNING THE VALUE IN DECLARED VAARIABLE THROUGH SELECT STATEMENT
     Select @COL=Column_NAME from tblUserInformation where UserId=@userid;
  END 
------------------ USE OF THE DECALRED VARAIBLE IN OTHER QUERY -------------
  SELECT * FROM SECOND_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @COL;

END
```